# Linux & Linux-Software: Advantages of a multi core processor

Tags: performance, cpu, parallelism

I plan to get a new notebook and try to find out if a quad-core processor gives me any advantages over a regular dual-core machine. I use common Linux Distributions (Ubuntu, Arch etc.) and mostly Graphics Software: Scribus, Inkscape, Gimp. I want to use this new processor for a few years.

I've done a lot of research but could not find any **reliable and up-to-date** answers. So:

The latest kernel makes use of multi core processors. But does that give me any noticeable advantages on a daily basis? I'm talking about regular multi-tasking with common Linux applications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't found any reliable answer because there is no widely applicable reliable answer. The performance gain from multiple cores is hard to predict except for well-defined tasks, and even then it can depend on many other factors such as available memory (no benefit from multiple cores if they're all waiting for some file to load).

For ordinary desktop use, you can generally gain responsiveness from having two cores: one to run the application from which you want a response, one to run GUI effects. The cores are idle most of the time but both do work when you start some task. Beyond two cores, the benefits tend to trail off. And even with two cores, a very lean GUI can mean that you don't get any benefit.

Parallelizing a single task is difficult; except for some very simple cases (for which the technical term is “embarrassingly parallel”) it requires significant effort from the programmer and is often plain not doable. Displaying a web page, for example, is a matter of positioning elements one by one and executing Javascript code, and it all needs to be done in order, so doesn't benefit from multiple cores. The benefit of multiple cores for web browsing is when you want to do something else while a complex web page is being rendered.

Some graphics software has parallel routines for large tasks (e.g. some transformations of large images). You will gain from multiple cores there, but again only for those tasks that have been written to take advantage of multiple processors. If you're going to run image transformations as background tasks, you'll definitely benefit from at least two cores (one for the task, one for interactive use) and possibly from more if the task itself takes advantage of multiple cores.

More than four cores is unlikely to give any benefit for a machine that doesn't do fancy things such as multiple simultaneous users, large compilations, large numerical calculations, etc. Two cores is likely to have some benefit over one for most tasks. Between two and four, it isn't clear-cut. A faster dual core will give more consistent benefits than going from dual to quad-core, but a faster clock speed has downsides as well, especially for a laptop, since it means the processor will use more power and require louder cooling.

Comment: This is a superb answer. Thank you very much for your effort!

Answer (score 3):

Many applications aren't explicitly multi-threaded, so their CPU-bound tasks will indeed be limited to one core at a time. Modern web browsers, however, use (at least) one core per window, so if you have multiple windows open you'll benefit from multiple cores.

More importantly, running Linux systems consists of many processes running, all taking turns using the CPU. Having multiple cores available means that, when two tasks want CPU time at the same time (which will happen a lot) the kernel doesn't have to choose. I find this makes a real difference in the responsiveness of the system.

Answer (score 1):

[Some operations](http://www.artistsguidetogimp.com/?p=267) in GIMP will take advantage of multiple cores; [others don't](https://askubuntu.com/questions/573969/gimp-uses-only-one-cpu-when-applying-a-gaussian-blur), but this is an [active area of development](http://wiki.gimp.org/wiki/Hacking:Porting_filters_to_GEGL) and should be expected to improve over time if you keep your version of GIMP up to date.